# my apikey of openAI will be rotated when i use vercel to deploy my server code,why?

Tags: nestjs, vercel, openai-api

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3b4tD.jpg)
i create a new Apikey in openAi, but it will be rotated when i deploy my backend.

i can use apikey build backend service normally!

Answer (score 0):

Are you also publishing your code on a public GitHub repository?

OpenAI has a system to detect if an API key has been leaked.

You should store the API key as an environment variable and not hard code it in your code.

in JavaScript you can then access it via `process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY` if you env variable is named `OPENAI_API_KEY`.

Comment: yeah, I set my repo public ....., thanks